# Can't access params in ActivatedRoute

Tags: angular, service, routes

I have a sub routing-module with a route like this:

```
path: 'zoneslist/desktop/:zoneid
```

I'm trying to access to zoneid from a service. I'm getting always null or undefined.

Given this constructor:

```
constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute){}
```

I tried the following solutions:

```
this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('zoneid')
this.route.snapshot.params['zoneid']
this.route.snapshot.params.zoneid
this.route.params.subscribe(
    (params: Params) => {
         console.log(params.get('id))
    }
);
```

Why am I getting null or undefined?

Answer (score 0):

I think you cant get route params in your service.
You should subscribe to them in ngOnInit in your Component and then pass them as a parameter in a function from your service

Comment: So there isn't a "cleaner way" to do that?

Comment: this is as clean as it gets